# Saving mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude into sqlite database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, mkmapview

I want to insert the value returning from mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude into my sqlite3 database. I am not sure of its type. I cannot do it this way:

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude floatValue], -1, nil);
```

It gives *"Cannot convert to a pointer type"* error because longitude is not float, I guess.

The type of field is FLOAT in the database table. How can I convert the value of longitude to float from whatever it is?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

Comment: For future reference @ozancali, you can simply hold down the option  key and double click on a property/variable and it'll tell you what type it is and provide a shortcut directly to the documentation and sample code for it. If instead you hold down the command key and double click, it'll bring you to directly to the header definition of the propery/variable.

Comment: That really helped me Jack, thanks a lot. I'm quite new to the IDE and the language, and have very limited time so I don't have the time to check the documentation, and even some basics. One more question, is there something like quick watch property of Visual Studio, which I can use during run-time to check values?

Comment: See the [Xcode Debugging Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/Xcode_Debugging.pdf) for details on watching variable values.  By the way, commenters aren't notified of your response unless you put @ in front of their userid.

Comment: @aBitObvious Oh I see, I also need to learn how to use Stackoverflow, I thought it had a notification system as in Facebook :) thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for MKUserLocation shows that the location property is of type CLLocation.  The docs for CLLocation show that the coordinate property is of type CLLocationCoordinate2D.

The [Core Location Data Types Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html) shows that CLLocationCoordinate2D is a struct containing latitude and longitude each of which is of type CLLocationDegrees.

On the same page, CLLocationDegrees is shown to be just another name for `double`.  So latitude and longitude are of type double.

So instead of using `sqlite3_bind_text`, use `sqlite3_bind_double`:

```
sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 1, mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude);
```

and to load the value, you would use something like:

```
double longitude = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, column_index_here);
```

Comment: Yeah that helped, thank you. I should've checked the sqlite methods, but didn't have time so asked directly here, sorry about that.