# How to save the values of coordinates in SQLite database

Tags: iphone, sqlite, mapkit

I am creating a map in which I am tracking the user's current location. When the current location of the user is traced their a pin is placed. Depending on this I get the latitude and longitude of current location.

I have an SQLite database which stores the latitude, longitude of the user. But my main problem is how to insert the coordinates of latitude and longitude in SQLite database. How can I do this?

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow (and it has attracted a LQ link-only answer). I will try to put it on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these links are useful to you.

[Saving mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude into sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635179/saving-mapview-userlocation-location-coordinate-longitude-into-sqlite-database)

[making map coordinates(lan,& long)storing in sqlite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630491/making-map-coordinateslan-longstoring-in-sqlite-database)

Comment: hi chetan i am having a doubt my coordinates are getting saved in my database but i have a problem.In my database i have created latitude and longitudes columns of type float and in code i am binding it as double so in the database my latitude and longitude coordinates are saved  somewhat like latitude:2.31164916423853e-310 and longitude:-1.98960878474239 what may be the problem .Please help me in solving this issue.thanks

Comment: if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1,&compiledStatement , NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {     sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement,1,mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude );
   sqlite3_bind_double(compiledStatement,2,mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude );
   double latitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 0);
   double longitude = sqlite3_column_double(compiledStatement, 1);
   location.latitude = latitude;
   location.longitude = longitude;  this is how i have inserted into my database.

Comment: @Rani, are you try to bind it with float?

Comment: actually my database columns in which i am saving latitude and longitude values is of float type but i am using sqlite3_bind_double statement to bind it and saving it in a double variable.

Comment: @Rani, Change column type float to double and then try.

Comment: then finally you need to store that value as a string and when you use it at that time convert it to double.

Comment: But how is it possible bcoz the value of longitude that i am getting from map is of float type

Comment: Its possible to store float type as a string.