# Drawing the polyline on the map in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Friend
I am trying to Drawing the polyline on the map.  For that I use this code.  It work fine.  Over here I use Fake_location(CSV file) but if I to want use the database location...  My database table is like this:

```
PK LocationID VARCHAR(20)
_id INTEGER
FK1 JourneyID VARCHAR(20)
Altitude FLOAT
Longitude FLOAT
Latitude FLOAT
Speed FLOAT
Accuracy FLOAT
LocationDate DATETIME
LastSyncDate DATETIME
```

How can I use Longitude & Latitude ?

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ROUTE_FILE_NAME ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString *fake_location = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    pointsArray = [[fake_location componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
    pointsArrayIndex = 0;
    oldLocationsIndex = 0;

    [fake_location release];

    oldLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}

-(void)startUpdatingLocation {
aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMER_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(injectNextLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)stopUpdatingLocation {
[aTimer invalidate];
}

-(void)injectNextLocation{

if (pointsArray.count == pointsArrayIndex) {
    [self stopUpdatingLocation];
    return;
}

CLLocation *oldLocation = nil;

if ([oldLocations count] > 0) {
    oldLocation = [oldLocations objectAtIndex:oldLocationsIndex];
    oldLocationsIndex++;
}

NSString *pointString = [pointsArray objectAtIndex:pointsArrayIndex];
NSArray *latLong = [pointString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
//NSLog(@"%@",latLong);

CLLocationCoordinate2D coords;
coords.latitude = [[latLong objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
coords.longitude = [[latLong objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

float altitude = [self getRandomValue:200 toMax:220];
CLLocation *myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithCoordinate:coords altitude:altitude horizontalAccuracy:1 verticalAccuracy:1 timestamp:[NSDate date]];

[self.delegate locationManager:self didUpdateToLocation:myLocation fromLocation:oldLocation];

[oldLocations addObject:myLocation];
[myLocation release];

pointsArrayIndex++;
}


-(void)dealloc {
[pointsArray release];
[aTimer release];
[oldLocations release];
[super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark functions

- (float) getRandomValue:(float)min toMax:(float)max {
NSNumber *rand;
rand = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:arc4random()];
return fmod([rand floatValue],(max-min+1))+min;
}
```

Comment: Very good question try this link for sqlite tutorial http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: This answer may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635179/saving-mapview-userlocation-location-coordinate-longitude-into-sqlite-database/4635609#4635609.

Comment: It was related to storing the location I done with But How i use this stored location into Map for Drawing the polyline on to the map  I am using the -(id)init methods which is releated to the .csv file which already have location of place on this place  i want use sqlite data  I want know how to use the database  data in the map for displaying the polyline